# How to dynamically change combobox when selecting different items in combobox

Tags: c#

```
  string sSql = "Select id from Master.Materialname where Material = '" +                
                    comboBox3.SelectedValue + "'"; 
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql,objConn1); 
  int mid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 
  string reffSql = "Select Process from Master.ProductionProcess where id = '" + mid + "'"; 
  SqlCommand rcmd = new SqlCommand(reffSql, objConn1); 
  comboBox4.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(rcmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

i have used above one but not working

Comment: I'm really not sure what the question is here friend. Please put some more context to it and try to be a bit clearer on your need.

Comment: Wellcome user187068. When you post code you should use `this style`. You also should to check your combobox and use parameters. Are you working with WPF, WinForms or ASP?

Comment: yes sir sure,   i have 2 combobox --combobox3 and combobo4 ,when user choose item in combo3 only  related value should be displayed in combo4

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will be filling the comboBox with both DisplayMember as well as ValueMember, while loading the comboBox data initially.

Initial Loading:

You should retrieve both the Id as well as Name fields from the table and bind it to your comboBoxes.

```
//Loading comboBox3
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id, Material from Master.Materialname", objConn1); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
da.Fill(dt); 
DataRow dr; 
dr = dt.NewRow(); 
comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Material"; 
comboBox3.ValueMember = "Id"; 
comboBox3.DataSource = dt; 

//Loading comboBox4
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id, Process from Master.ProductionProcess", objConn1); 
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); 
da1.Fill(dt1); 
DataRow dr1; 
dr1 = dt1.NewRow(); 
comboBox4.DisplayMember = "Process"; 
comboBox4.ValueMember = "Id"; 
comboBox4.DataSource = dt1; 
objConn1.Close();
```

Then in the combo3selectedIndex changed event,

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue) > 0)
    comboBox4.SelectedIndex = comboBox3.SelectedIndex;
```

The selectedValue of comboBox4 should change now.

Comment: unable to get sir could you please change in my query

Comment: ya on combobo3 i have filled the item on page load ...now when iam select one value in combo3 ...related value shoud display in combo4 ..but still combo4 not filled

Comment: you should do this in comboBox selectedIndex changed event. try coding with `where` clause of SQL in it.

Comment: @user187068: Can you show how you have loaded the comboxes in the page load.

Comment: try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Material  from Master.Materialname", objConn1);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                DataRow dr;
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                
               
                comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Material";
                comboBox3.ValueMember = "Material";
                comboBox3.DataSource = dt;
                objConn1.Close();
            }

Comment: there are 2 table  and mid is primary key on both table

Comment: @Sandeep: thx for support sir..                                                                       i have ammend the code but give error:InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Comment: @Sandeep: yes but same error... iwan post the image of sql tables how shoud i post??

Comment: go to `edit` and there will be an option for uploading image in top bar of body text.

Comment: 2 table 1 table is material name with column Id, Material --with value is AFA IN MATERIAL AND 1 IN ID.

Comment: 2ND TABLE IS ProductionProcess  WITH PROCESS,ID,MATERIALID WITH VALUE IS WRAPPING,1,1

Comment: WHEN I SELECT AFA IN COMBO3 **WRAPPING ** SHOULD COMING ON COMBO4

Answer (score 0):

```
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id, Material from Master.Materialname", objConn1); 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    da.Fill(dt); 
    DataRow dr; 
    dr = dt.NewRow(); 
    comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Material"; 
    comboBox3.ValueMember = "Id"; 
    comboBox3.DataSource = dt; 

write below code on combobox3 changed event

    int newid = comboBox3.selectedvalue;

    //Loading comboBox4
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select Id, Process from Master.ProductionProcess and Id = " + newid , objConn1); 
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); 
    da1.Fill(dt1); `enter code here`
    DataRow dr1; 
    dr1 = dt1.NewRow(); 
    comboBox4.DisplayMember = "Process"; 
    comboBox4.ValueMember = "Id"; 
    comboBox4.DataSource = dt1; 
    objConn1.Close();
```

Comment: Error 7 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'selectedvalue' and no extension method 'selectedvalue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\Spareage\Lib\CRSpareageFinance\GateForm\InventoryEntry.cs 140 36 CRSpareageFinance

Comment: 2 table 1 table is material name with column Id, Material --with value is AFA IN MATERIAL AND 1 IN ID. – user187068 29 mins ago 
 
2ND TABLE IS ProductionProcess WITH PROCESS,ID,MATERIALID WITH VALUE IS WRAPPING,1,1 – user187068 26 mins ago 
 
WHEN I SELECT AFA IN COMBO3 **WRAPPING ** SHOULD COMING ON COMBO4

Comment: @user187068 Tell me in theory what is your problem? If you want to post code then post it in your question not here. Using `where` clause should solve your problem.

Comment: combo4 not filled is my problem sir

Comment: @user187068 try `where` clause in selectedIndex changed event of combobox3 to fill the comboBox4 items.

Comment: private void comboBox3_SelectedInde(object sender, EventArg e)
        {
            string sql2= "select process from Master.ProductionProcess as  a inner join Master.Materialname as b on a.Material = b.mid  WHERE b.material ='" + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql2,objConn1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            comboBox4.DisplayMember = "process";
            comboBox4.ValueMember = "process";
            comboBox4.DataSource = dt;
        }